# How can I use dame database for two different site php not using any cms?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to run two sites using single database one cpanel-phpmyadmin how can i access to another site to that same database uploaded on one site.

for 1st site i use code for connect to database

```
mysql_connect("localhost","User","password");
mysql_select_db("database");
```

what will be the database connection code in php so that i can assess one database to multipal sites...

Comment: connection strings are NOT specific to an application, they are specific to the database. In short, the same connection string can be used from multiple applications, providing the installation of the site can find the DB and has correct security access etc.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should check your MySQL settings to make sure that it allows remote connections. If remote connections are allowed, from remote server you can connect in a similar way by specifying your current server's IP address instead of "localhost" where database is running, i.e. if database is running on the server with IP address 123.123.123.123, then the code will look like:

```
mysql_connect("123.123.123.123","User","password");
mysql_select_db("database");
```

Comment: How can i check MySQL settings that it allows remote connections in WHM cpanel

Comment: You can use the following guide: http://kb.liquidweb.com/enable-remote-mysql-connections-in-cpanel/

Answer (score 0):

At first you should check your MySQL settings to make sure that it allows remote connections. If remote connections are allowed, from remote server you can connect in a similar way by specifying your current server's IP address instead of "localhost" where database is running, i.e. if database is running on the server with IP address 123.123.123.123, then the code will look like:

> mysql_connect("123.123.123.123","User","password");
>
> mysql_select_db("database");

you can try this